# Why extractLBPfeatures() function shows vectors containg 10 values?

Tags: matlab

I used extractLBPfeatures() in my experimental image.I found 10 values when i used extractLBPFeatures(image,'Upright',false).
why i got 10 values for 'false' value.
Moreover,i also get the values in a normilazation form.How it calculates?